# Terraform for_each, Count Index

Tags: loops, google-cloud-platform, foreach, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to access all the values from a for_each statement in `google_compute_instance` resource

I want to get all the `values [dev-1, dev-2]` in the`name` attribute and parse it to `vm_name` in my `metadata_startup_script`

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "compute_instance" {
  project  = var.project_id
  for_each = toset(["1", "2"])
  name     = "dev-${each.key}"
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone         = "${var.region}-b"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-1804-lts"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"
    access_config {
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }
  
  metadata_startup_script = templatefile("copy.tftpl", {
    vm_name         = "${google_compute_instance.compute_instance.0.name}"
    nfs_ip          = "${google_filestore_instance.instance.networks[0].ip_addresses[0]}"
    file_share_name = "${google_filestore_instance.instance.file_shares[0].name}"
    zone            = "${var.region}-b"
  })
}
```

I am unable to get all compute instance from the `name` argument

I get this error message

```
╷
│ Error: Cycle: google_compute_instance.compute_instance["2"], google_compute_instance.compute_instance["1"]
│ 
│
```

How do I resolve this issue so I can get all the virtual machine name and parse it to `vm_name` variable?

Comment: Are you certain you do not want the value for the `name` argument instead? If you do not want all of the values for the `name` argument, then is it safe to assume the `vm_name` var is a `list` type?

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard I want ```vm_name``` to get all the values like this  ```[“dev-1”, “dev-2”]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the hardcoded elements in your `for_each` to a variable,
and pass that to your vm_name, something like this:

```txt
locals {
  compute_names = ["dev-1", "dev-2"]
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "compute_instance" {
  project      = var.project_id
  for_each     = toset(local.compute_names)
  name         = each.key
  machine_type = "e2-micro"
  zone         = "${var.region}-b"

...
  
  metadata_startup_script = templatefile("copy.tftpl", {
    vm_name         = local.compute_names
...
    zone            = "${var.region}-b"
  })
}
```